# Ramda- how to convert 2 children arrays in object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, ramda.js

I have an object

```
const data = {
    t1: [ {"a": 1, "a1": 2}, {"b": 3, "b1": 4}, {"c": 5, "c1": 6} ], 
    t2: [ {"d": 2}, {"e": 2}, {"f": 2} ]
}
```

I want to convert object above into an array

```
[ {"a": 1, "a1": 2}, {"b": 3, "b1": 4}, {"c": 5, "c1": 6} , {"d": 2}, {"e": 2}, {"f": 2}]
```

I can do it with this code

```
const join = data.t1.concat(data.t2)
```

Is there any function in `Ramda` can do the similar task ?

Comment: Ramda has [R.concat](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#concat). The main difference is that R.concat is curried, and has a fixed arity of 2.

Comment: There is no single function, but `compose (flatten, values) (data)` should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use `Array.values` and `Array.reduce`

or if your browser/node support `Array.flat` you can use that

like this

```js
const join = data => Object.values(data).reduce((res, v) => [...res, ...v])
const join2 = data => Object.values(data).flat()

const data = {
    t1: [ {"a": 1, "a1": 2}, {"b": 3, "b1": 4}, {"c": 5, "c1": 6} ], 
    t2: [ {"d": 2}, {"e": 2}, {"f": 2} ]
}

console.log(join(data))
console.log(join2(data))
```